# Not able to clear floats in responsive css

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, css-float

I am creating a mobile screen specific set of style in my css.

HTML

```
<div id="rowlinks">
   <div class="rlleft">
          <div class="rllefta"> 
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
         </div>

       <div class="rlleftb">
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
       </div>
 </div>

    <div class="rlright">
        <div class="rlrighta">
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
      </div>

       <div class="rlrightb">
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
       </div>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#rowlinks{clear:both;padding:10px;background-color:whitesmoke;margin-top:10px;border:1px solid grey;border-style:outset}
#rowlinks a{color:black;text-decoration:none;font-size:16px}

 .rlleft{width:45%;float:left;}
   .rllefta{float:left;width:45%;padding:10px;}
   .rlleftb{float:right;width:45%;padding:10px;}

.rlright{width:45%;float:right;}
   .rlrighta{float:left;width:45%;padding:10px;}
   .rlrightb{float:right;width:45%;padding:10px;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    #rowlinks{clear:both;width:95%;margin:0px auto;}
    #rowlinks div{clear:both;width:95%;margin:0px auto;border:1px solid maroon}
    #rowlinks a{clear:both;margin:0 auto;font-size:16px;;width:80%}

 }
```

Now my issuse is,

Though all the divs lay out horizontally perfect on desktop and bigger screens, on mobile layout as I have shown, I want it to stack one below the other in symmetry. I have used clear:both for clearing floats. However, it is not clearing the floats and is not stacking one below the other.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to remove `float: left`, add `float: none`.

Comment: What about the right floats ? Will work for that too ? Let me check...

Comment: `float: none` removes all floats.

Comment: Bang on @3rdthemagical ! Thanks a ton ! Worked like a charm ! How do I accept this as the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `float: left`, add `float: none`. `Float: none` removes all floats.